# remove a tab/ space in c program

Tags: c, tabs, spaces

I'm trying to prevent printing a trailing tab at the end of each row of output.
How can I do this?

The rest of the code works as I need it to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    int i, j, k, y, z, x, c, b, a, C;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(j=0; j<x; j++){
            int c = 0;
            for(k=0; k<x; k++){

                y = (i+1)*(k+1);
                z = (j+k); 
                c = (z*y)+c;
            } 
            printf("%d\t", c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did vote to close: there's nothing that shows you actually _tried_ anything... even a simple google search for _"C output tab new line"_ would've given you your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\t` and `\n` are the tab and new-line escape sequences respectively, so change

```
printf("%d\t", c);
```

to

```
printf("%d", c);
```

to get rid of the tab, and remove

```
printf("\n");
```

all together, to loose the new lines... easy
As an asside: why are you declaring a second `int c`? Your code starts with declaring bunch of ints, some of which you don't use:

```
int i, j, k, y, z, x, c, b, a, C;
                        //last 3 aren't used
                      //c declared here, though
//I'd write:
int i, j, k, y, z, x, c;
```

And further down:

```
//inside second loop:
int c = 0;
//would be better if wou wrote:
c = 0;
```

Last of the notes: you're missing a `return` statement, but your `main` function's signature indicates (rightly) the main function should return an int, not a void.
Add a `return 0;` at the end

If the only thing you want to avoid printing is the *last* \n (and \t), you could change:

```
printf("\n");
```

with

```
if (i < x-1) printf("\n");
```

This will print \n every time, except for the *last* time your loop runs. Simply because the condition for the loop to run is `i<x`, and the condition for the newline to be printed is `i<x-1`.
As far as your tabs are concerned, replacing:

```
 printf("%d\t", c);
```

with:

```
if (j < x - 1) printf("%d\t", c);
else printf("%d", c);
```

does just what you need.
That said, since `x` is a constant value, it would probably be better to assign `x-1` to one of those unused, yet declared ints:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
a = x -1;
```

Then, since you're checking when you're printing the last number of a row with this code:

```
if (j < a) printf("%d\t", c);//replaced x - 1 with a here
else printf("%d", c);
```

You can safely assume that the `else` clause is only applicable to the last number of each row, so why not add the newline there?

```
if (j < a) printf("%d\t", c);//replaced x - 1 with a here
else printf("%d\n", c);
```

Overall, this leaves you with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    int i, j, k, y, z, x, c, a;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    a = x - 1;
    i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(j=0; j<x; j++){
            c = 0;
            for(k=0; k<x; k++){
                y = (i+1)*(k+1);
                z = (j+k); 
                c = (z*y)+c;
            } 
            if (j < a) printf("%d\t", c);
            else printf("%d\n", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;//ADD A RETURN STATEMENT!!
}
```

This still adds a new line after the last row of output. To remove that, too, just write:

```
if (j < a) printf("%d\t", c);
else if (i < a) printf("%d\n", c);//check if we're in the last i-loop
else printf("%d", c);//if so, don't print new line
```

Job done... I've tried this code [and you can see the output on this codepad](http://codepad.org/yPxZYQ4p)

Comment: I need the Tab and the new line. but at the end of the raw it prints it and there i want to delete it. deleting the last one

Comment: @user1465662: Ok, now I get what you're asking. Just a piece of advice: _"raw"_ means unprocessed, uncooked, crude, unfinished. Whereas _"row"_ means a sequence, an ordered/structured format.

Answer (score 1):

`\t` means tab, `\n` means new line. These are called [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Sequences_in_C).